# Comparing version number strings (major, minor, revision, beta)

Tags: java, regex, versioning

I have an application that communicates with the firmware of a device. As there are changes to the firmware, it is versioned with the format `{major}.{minor}.{revision}[beta[{beta}]]`. To give you a few examples, the current version is `0.4.7beta` which will be followed by `0.4.7beta2` and occasionally `0.4.7`, followed by `0.4.8beta`. The versioning format of the firmware is unfortunately not under my control, so I can not change it.

I need a way of comparing firmwares with each other. Basically, I need a function

```
boolean isFirmwareNewer(String testFW, String baseFW);
```

What I did so far was to convert this format to a simple `int`. So `0.4.7beta2` will become `00040702` (2 digits for each level). The problem is, that

1. My code is difficult to read (>40 lines and 3 methods)
2. I am sure, there is a elegant solution to this (maybe using regex?)
3. I want to have a wildcard `0.0.0` which is newer by definition
4. This handles the beta versions incorrect (`0.4.7beta2` is not newer than `0.4.7`). That is easy to account for (`if (testFW.contains("beta")) testFWValue -= 100;`, but it's not really elegant as well.

How do you guys do this normally (or how would you do it)?

If you want, I can attach the code I am currently working with, but as I said, it's >40 lines of code and not really readable (which is the reason why I am looking for a better way to do this).

Comment: `0.4.7` is newer than `0.4.7beta2` right?

Comment: @aioobe Oops, thanks, I will correct that in the post. ;)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here's one suggestion:

```
static int[] getVersionNumbers(String ver) {
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)(beta(\\d*))?")
                       .matcher(ver);
    if (!m.matches())
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Malformed FW version");

    return new int[] { Integer.parseInt(m.group(1)),  // major
            Integer.parseInt(m.group(2)),             // minor
            Integer.parseInt(m.group(3)),             // rev.
            m.group(4) == null ? Integer.MAX_VALUE    // no beta suffix
                    : m.group(5).isEmpty() ? 1        // "beta"
                    : Integer.parseInt(m.group(5))    // "beta3"
    };
}

static boolean isFirmwareNewer(String testFW, String baseFW) {

    int[] testVer = getVersionNumbers(testFW);
    int[] baseVer = getVersionNumbers(baseFW);

    for (int i = 0; i < testVer.length; i++)
        if (testVer[i] != baseVer[i])
            return testVer[i] > baseVer[i];

    return true;
}
```

It uses a little trick and translates the beta-part as follows:

- `""` (no beta suffix) → Beta MAX_INT
- `"beta"` → Beta 1 (since it preceeds "beta2")
- `"betaX"` → Beta X

Note that it return `true` if both versions are identical.

Comment: I like that approach. It is much cleaner than my current version and handles the beta stuff more elegant than I do. Thanks! (and it is perfectly fine, if it returns true if identical, that's what I want)

Comment: ...oh right. You may want to add `if (testFW.equals("0.0.0")) return true`.

Comment: Already did that. ;) But that is a special case and it's ok to not include it in your answer I guess.

Answer (score 10):

I would implement a comparable class:

```
class Version implements Comparable<Version> {
    int major;
    int minor;
    int rev;
    int beta = Integer.MAX_VALUE;


    public int compareTo(Version o) {
        if (this.major != o.major) {
            return Integer.compare(this.major, o.major);
        }
        if (this.minor != o.minor) {
            return Integer.compare(this.minor, o.minor);
        }
        if (this.rev != o.rev) {
            return Integer.compare(this.rev, o.rev);
        }
        if (this.beta != o.beta) {
            return Integer.compare(this.beta, o.beta);
        }
        return 0;
    }


    public static Version parse(String version) {
        // TODO: implement parsing here
        // 1.1.1      - beta = MAX_VALUE
        // 1.1.1beta  - beta = 1
        // 1.1.1beta2 - beta = 2
        return new Version();
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "" + major + "." + minor + "." + rev
                + (beta == Integer.MAX_VALUE ? "" 
                        : (beta == 1 ? "beta" : 
                            ("beta" + beta)));
    }


}
```

Then compare in a standard java way:

```
if (Version.parse(testFW).compareTo(Version.parse(baseFW)) < 0) {
   // Version is newer!
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think that is a little bit overkill for my needs, but it would be a clean solution. +1

Comment: Just a tip, use [`Integer.compare`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compare%28int,%20int%29) instead of subtracting the integers. That solution is overflow-friendlier, and slightly more readable.

Comment: ...especially since you're actually mentioning `Integer.MAX_VALUE` in the same code snippet ;-)

Answer (score 3):

For my project I have used this approach by following [Semantic Versioning 2.0.0](http://semver.org):

```
private static String[] formatVersionString(String[] strArr){
    //remove trailing 0s
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    boolean foundChar = false;
    for(int i=strArr.length-1;i>=0;i--){
        String curChar = strArr[i];
        if(curChar.equals("0") && !foundChar){
            continue;
        } else{
            list.add(strArr[i]);
            foundChar = true;
        }

    }
    Collections.reverse(list);
    return list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
}

private static String getPreReleaseBuildStr(String buildStr){
    //removing build metadata
    if(buildStr == null){
        return null;
    }
    String [] a = buildStr.split("\\+");
    if(a.length>0){
        return a[0];
    } else{
        return null;
    }
}

private static int compareVersionString(String str1,String str2){
    int ret = 0;
    String[] verStr1 = formatVersionString(str1.split("\\."));
    String[] verStr2 = formatVersionString(str2.split("\\."));

    int i = 0;
    // set index to first non-equal ordinal or length of shortest version string
    while (i < verStr1.length && i < verStr2.length && verStr1[i].equals(verStr2[i])) {
        i++;
    }

    // compare first non-equal ordinal number
    if (i < verStr1.length && i < verStr2.length) {
        int diff = 0;
        try{
            if(verStr1[i] == null || verStr1[i].trim().length() == 0) {
                verStr1[i] = "0";
            }
            if(verStr2[i] == null || verStr2[i].trim().length() == 0) {
                verStr2[i] = "0";
            }
            diff = Integer.valueOf(verStr1[i]).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(verStr2[i]));
        }catch(NumberFormatException e){
            diff = verStr1[i].compareTo(verStr2[i]);
        } finally{
            ret = Integer.signum(diff);
        }
    } else{
        // the strings are equal or one string is a substring of the other
        // e.g. "1.2.3" = "1.2.3" or "1.2.3" < "1.2.3.4"

        ret = Integer.signum(verStr1.length - verStr2.length);
    }

    return ret;
}

/**
 * Compares two version strings.
 * follow this link for more info http://semver.org/
 *
 * Use this instead of String.compareTo() for a non-lexicographical
 * comparison that works for version strings. e.g. "1.10".compareTo("1.6").
 *
 * Ex:--
 * //1.0.0-alpha < 1.0.0-alpha.1 < 1.0.0-alpha.beta < 1.0.0-beta < 1.0.0-beta.2 < 1.0.0-beta.11 < 1.0.0-rc.1 < 1.0.0 < 2.0.0.6
 *
 * @param str1 a string of ordinal numbers separated by decimal points.
 * @param str2 a string of ordinal numbers separated by decimal points.
 * @return The result is a negative integer if str1 is _numerically_ less than str2.
 *         The result is a positive integer if str1 is _numerically_ greater than str2.
 *         The result is zero if the strings are _numerically_ equal.
 */

public static int versionCompare(String str1, String str2) {

    int ret = 0;
    String[] val1 = str1.split("-");
    String[] val2 = str2.split("-");

    String preReleaseVer1 = null, preReleaseVer2 = null;
    if(val1.length>1){
        preReleaseVer1 = getPreReleaseBuildStr(val1[1]);
    }
    if(val2.length>1){
        preReleaseVer2 = getPreReleaseBuildStr(val2[1]);
    }

    ret = compareVersionString(val1[0],val2[0]);

    if(ret == 0){
        //if both version are equal then compare with pre_release String
        if(preReleaseVer1 == null && preReleaseVer2 == null){
              ret = 0;
        } else if(preReleaseVer1 == null && preReleaseVer2!=null){
            //1.0.0 > 1.0.0-beta
              ret = 1;
        } else if(preReleaseVer1 != null && preReleaseVer2==null){
            //1.0.0-beta < 1.0.0
            ret = -1;
        } else{
            //both hasve pre release string
            ret = compareVersionString(preReleaseVer1,preReleaseVer2);
        }
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Use versionCompare(String str1, String str2) method for any comparison

**Code Example:---**

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        //1.0.0-alpha < 1.0.0-alpha.1 < 1.0.0-alpha.beta < 1.0.0-beta < 1.0.0-beta.2 < 1.0.0-beta.11 < 1.0.0-rc.1 < 1.0.0

        Test(new String[]{"1.0.0-alpha","1.0.0-alpha.1","1.0.0-alpha.beta","1.0.0-beta",
        "1.0.0-beta.2","1.0.0-beta.11","1.0.0-rc.1","1.0.0","2.0.0.1"});  
    }
    private static void Test(String[] versions) {
        for (int i = 0; i < versions.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < versions.length; j++) {
            Test(versions[i], versions[j]);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void Test(String v1, String v2) {
        int result = versionCompare(v1,v2);
        String op = "==";
        if (result < 0) op = "<";
        if (result > 0) op = ">";
        System.out.printf("%s %s %s\n", v1, op, v2);
    }
}
```

**The Output of the above example is given below:---**

```
1.0.0-alpha == 1.0.0-alpha
1.0.0-alpha < 1.0.0-alpha.1
1.0.0-alpha < 1.0.0-alpha.beta
1.0.0-alpha < 1.0.0-beta
1.0.0-alpha < 1.0.0-beta.2
1.0.0-alpha < 1.0.0-beta.11
1.0.0-alpha < 1.0.0-rc.1
1.0.0-alpha < 1.0.0
1.0.0-alpha < 2.0.0.1
1.0.0-alpha.1 > 1.0.0-alpha
1.0.0-alpha.1 == 1.0.0-alpha.1
1.0.0-alpha.1 < 1.0.0-alpha.beta
1.0.0-alpha.1 < 1.0.0-beta
1.0.0-alpha.1 < 1.0.0-beta.2
1.0.0-alpha.1 < 1.0.0-beta.11
1.0.0-alpha.1 < 1.0.0-rc.1
1.0.0-alpha.1 < 1.0.0
1.0.0-alpha.1 < 2.0.0.1
1.0.0-alpha.beta > 1.0.0-alpha
1.0.0-alpha.beta > 1.0.0-alpha.1
1.0.0-alpha.beta == 1.0.0-alpha.beta
1.0.0-alpha.beta < 1.0.0-beta
1.0.0-alpha.beta < 1.0.0-beta.2
1.0.0-alpha.beta < 1.0.0-beta.11
1.0.0-alpha.beta < 1.0.0-rc.1
1.0.0-alpha.beta < 1.0.0
1.0.0-alpha.beta < 2.0.0.1
1.0.0-beta > 1.0.0-alpha
1.0.0-beta > 1.0.0-alpha.1
1.0.0-beta > 1.0.0-alpha.beta
1.0.0-beta == 1.0.0-beta
1.0.0-beta < 1.0.0-beta.2
1.0.0-beta < 1.0.0-beta.11
1.0.0-beta < 1.0.0-rc.1
1.0.0-beta < 1.0.0
1.0.0-beta < 2.0.0.1
1.0.0-beta.2 > 1.0.0-alpha
1.0.0-beta.2 > 1.0.0-alpha.1
1.0.0-beta.2 > 1.0.0-alpha.beta
1.0.0-beta.2 > 1.0.0-beta
1.0.0-beta.2 == 1.0.0-beta.2
1.0.0-beta.2 < 1.0.0-beta.11
1.0.0-beta.2 < 1.0.0-rc.1
1.0.0-beta.2 < 1.0.0
1.0.0-beta.2 < 2.0.0.1
1.0.0-beta.11 > 1.0.0-alpha
1.0.0-beta.11 > 1.0.0-alpha.1
1.0.0-beta.11 > 1.0.0-alpha.beta
1.0.0-beta.11 > 1.0.0-beta
1.0.0-beta.11 > 1.0.0-beta.2
1.0.0-beta.11 == 1.0.0-beta.11
1.0.0-beta.11 < 1.0.0-rc.1
1.0.0-beta.11 < 1.0.0
1.0.0-beta.11 < 2.0.0.1
1.0.0-rc.1 > 1.0.0-alpha
1.0.0-rc.1 > 1.0.0-alpha.1
1.0.0-rc.1 > 1.0.0-alpha.beta
1.0.0-rc.1 > 1.0.0-beta
1.0.0-rc.1 > 1.0.0-beta.2
1.0.0-rc.1 > 1.0.0-beta.11
1.0.0-rc.1 == 1.0.0-rc.1
1.0.0-rc.1 < 1.0.0
1.0.0-rc.1 < 2.0.0.1
1.0.0 > 1.0.0-alpha
1.0.0 > 1.0.0-alpha.1
1.0.0 > 1.0.0-alpha.beta
1.0.0 > 1.0.0-beta
1.0.0 > 1.0.0-beta.2
1.0.0 > 1.0.0-beta.11
1.0.0 > 1.0.0-rc.1
1.0.0 == 1.0.0
1.0.0 < 2.0.0.1
2.0.0.1 > 1.0.0-alpha
2.0.0.1 > 1.0.0-alpha.1
2.0.0.1 > 1.0.0-alpha.beta
2.0.0.1 > 1.0.0-beta
2.0.0.1 > 1.0.0-beta.2
2.0.0.1 > 1.0.0-beta.11
2.0.0.1 > 1.0.0-rc.1
2.0.0.1 > 1.0.0
2.0.0.1 == 2.0.0.1
3.5.6-beta == 3.5.6-beta
3.5.6-beta == 3.5.6-beta.0
3.5.6-beta.0 == 3.5.6-beta
3.5.6-beta.0 == 3.5.6-beta.0
```